# Having trouble with KISSing

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

There's a bit of a weird piece in my API that I'm not too happy about, but I can't seem to see any other way of going about.

It involves a `IFunctionalityFactory` abstract factory:

```
public interface IFunctionalityFactory
{
    IFunctionality Create();
}
```

An `IFunctionality` interface:

```
public interface IFunctionality
{
    void Execute();
    string AuthId { get; }
    bool IsAuthorised { get; }
}
```

Sample implementation - I don't like that, because most functionalities will have pretty much exactly the same identical code, except for the type name... although I like how simple and straightforward this code has become:

```
public class SomeFunctionality : FunctionalityBase
{
    private readonly IView _view;

    public SomeFunctionality(bool canExecute, IView view) 
        : base(canExecute)
    {
        _view = view;
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        _view.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Here's the base class:

```
public abstract class FunctionalityBase : IFunctionality
{
    private bool _canExecute;

    protected FunctionalityBase(bool canExecute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public virtual void Execute()
    {
        // Templated method.
        // Must override in all derived classes.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IFunctionality.Execute()
    {
        if (_canExecute)
        {
            Execute();
        }
        else
        {
            // client code should catch and gracefully handle this exception:
            throw new NotAuthorizedException(resx.Functionality_Execute_NotAuthorised);
        }
    }

    string IFunctionality.AuthId
    {
        get { return GetType().FullName; }
    }

    bool IFunctionality.IsAuthorised
    {
        get { return _canExecute; }
    }
}
```

Also involves a `IFunctionalityAuthorisation` interface:

```
public interface IFunctionalityAuthorisation
{
    bool IsAuthorised(string authId);
}
```

The idea is that there's a database table that associates a string (`AuthId`) with zero or more ActiveDirectory groups; if there's no entry for a given AuthId, then the functionality is authorised for everyone. If there's one or more entries, it's only authorised for the users in the listed groups.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
public class SomeFunctionalityFactory : IFunctionalityFactory
{
    private readonly IFunctionalityAuthorisation _auth;
    private readonly IView _view;
    private readonly ISomeFunctionalityViewModel _viewModel;

    public SomeFunctionalityFactory(IFunctionalityAuthorisation auth, 
                                    IView view, ISomeFunctionalityViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _auth = auth;
        _view = view;
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public IFunctionality Create()
    {
        var canExecute = _auth.IsAuthorised(typeof(SomeFunctionality).FullName);
        _view.DataContext = _viewModel;
        return new SomeFunctionality(canExecute, _view);
    }
}
```

If a functionality factory has a `IFunctionalityAuthorisation` in its constructor, it receives this implementation:

```
public class FunctionalityAuthorisation : IFunctionalityAuthorisation
{
    private readonly ICurrentUser _user;
    private readonly ISecurityModel _model;

    public FunctionalityAuthorisation(ICurrentUser user, ISecurityModel model)
    {
        _user = user;
        _model = model;
    }

    public bool IsAuthorised(string authId)
    {
        var authorizedGroups = _model.AuthorizedRoles(authId);
        var result = !authorizedGroups.Any() || _user.Groups.Any(authorizedGroups.Contains);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The main issue I'm having with this approach, is that since I'm going to be injecting dozens of `IFunctionalityFactory` into the constructors of many modules, so I need to tell my IoC container to differenciate between them, and I'm using Ninject so I'm using `InjectAttribute`:

```
_kernel.Bind<IFunctionalityFactory>()
       .To<SomeFunctionalityFactory>()
       .WhenTargetHas<SomeAttribute>(); // SomeAttribute : InjectAttribute

_kernel.Bind<IFunctionalityFactory>()
       .To<AnotherFunctionalityFactory>()
       .WhenTargetHas<AnotherAttribute>(); // AnotherAttribute : InjectAttribute
```

And so on and so forth. If I have 200 functionalities to implement, I'm going to have 200 kernel bindings, and I hate that. Especially when the rest of the assembly's dependencies are configured like this:

```
_kernel.Bind(t => t.From(_businessLayerAssembly)
                   .SelectAllClasses()
                   .BindDefaultInterface());
```

Another issue I'm having with this approach (perhaps the main one), is that a functionality gets fully resolved, View, ViewModel, Model and all, even if it's never called, even if the user isn't even authorised to execute it. With the 3 functionalities I have now it's not much of an issue, but when I get to 200 it's certainly going to bite me, and if someone takes over my code in 5 years it will be one of the first things they WTF over, I'm sure.

Might be worth saying that this project is a C# rewrite (.net 4.0 / VS2010 with EF 4.4) of a crippled VB6 app that needs to be done while keeping the VB6 code in production, as it is business-critical code; it will be rewritten in small chunks, one functionality at a time - hence the "functionality" approach. The VB6 code needs to know if a functionality can or can't be executed, because until the "switchboard" forms that hold all the functionalities are redone in XAML, I want them to use the COM-visible `IFunctionality` interface to determine whether or not to draw the associated button.

Lastly, this is what the code is like after major refactorings, which have greatly simplified lots of things. I believe there's still a few layers of useless complexity, but I need your help to see where it's at, at this point. I'm not asking for specific answers regarding how I could address some of the specific issues I'm having (e.g. the `NinjectAttribute` issue), rather to be told exactly what's wrong with this approach (I might "not like" something that's just the way it has to be), why, and what would be a better way.

Comment: Small note, I'd make `private bool _canExecute;` in `FunctionalityBase` `readonly`.

Comment: Dang, how did I miss that!! Thanks! ...that's all?

Comment: Well, likely not all, but I thought I'd mention that quickly :) I do find the general approach rather clean though.

Comment: If `FunctionalityBase`'s `Execute` only throws a `NotImplementedException`, why not make the `Execute` within `FunctionalityBase` abstract?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First: Don't create a base class with a virtual method which simply throws. This moves problem detection from compile time (abstract member not implemented won't compile) to run time (forgotten to override or accidentally called base throws) - usually undesirable. Virtual method says "You can override me if you want but you don't have to".

Now your actual problem.

Let me see if I understand correctly what you are saying:

- You have N classes of type `XyzFunctionality`
- You also have N corresponding factory classes of type `XyzFunctionalityFactory` each responsible of creating the specific `XyzFunctionality`
- You also have N corresponding `RequiresXyzFunctionality` attributes which you use to inject the specific `XyzFunctionalityFactory` for `IFunctionalityFactory` members

Is that basically correct? If yes then this smells to me:

If you have a member in a class of type `IFunctionalityFactory` then this basically says: "I want a factory which can create `IFunctionality` objects for me and do not care what they actually do" while in fact this is big fat lie - why else would you decorate with an attribute saying "actually this requires a very specific functionality factory"?

If the application requires that object Foo gets injected with a specific functionality factory then express it by making the type `SomeFunctionalityFactory` rather then `IFunctionalityFactory` - no 200 attributes, no 200 kernel bindings.

Now you will probably say "What about unit testing"?

1. You could make a `FunctionalityFactoryBase` class similar to your `FunctionalityBase` class with a virtual `Create` however that's not a good idea for the same reasons why it's not a good idea for `FunctionalityBase`.
2. Make `Create` virtual in all factories. Easy to forget.
3. Create a marker interface `IXyzFunctionalityFactory` and use that instead. Smells.

I think I'd go with the first option. The factories are all very light and really only contain `Create` so it's unlikely the implementer will forget to overwrite it. Unit tests should catch inadvertent calls of the base class method.

I might have assumed totally incorrectly though so please correct me if I'm wrong in my assumptions.

Comment: I remember having a fight with myself at one point over the virtual vs abstract Execute method. I should have commented the why of this because now I can't remember but I think it has to do with calling it from the explicit interface implementation, but I've just tested it through COM interop with the `abstract` method and it works, so I'll change that! Your assumptions are correct :)

Comment: So I end up with `ISomeFunctionalityFactory` and I can bind to default interface, this solves the InjectAttribute issue but I end up with abstract factory galore... There has to be a design flaw I'm not seeing that can be reworked so as to not need those factories at all, no?

Comment: Hmm the way I have it, if auth configs are modified the app needs to be restarted to take effect, since functionalities are auhorised at composition. So I can make IFunctionalityAuthorisation a dependency of functionalities and evaluate IsAuthorised during CanExecute and then I don't need factories anymore, but I do need ISomeFunctionality for kernel bindings to go by convention... and that's a marker interface, but benefits outweight the smell I find.

Comment: @retailcoder: Well, if you got rid of the factories and leave your virtual `Execute` and possibly `CanExecute` in your functionality base class then you could simply spell out the dependency `SomeFunctionality` explicitly and stub the concrete class in your unit tests by overriding them. Saves you a ton of marker interfaces.